# appwrite RealTime query with Query.equal(attribute, value) as Databases, is it possible?

Tags: appwrite

I want to make an AppWrite RealTime subscription with parameters, for example Query.equal (attribute, value), as it is possible to make a request in Databases

```
final databases = Databases (client);
```

```
final documents = await databases.listDocuments( '[DATABASE_ID]', '[COLLECTION_ID]', [ Query.equal('title', ['Avatar', 'Lord of the Rings']), Query.greaterThan('year', 1999) ]);
```

Is it possible to make the same requests in RealTime as is possible in Firebase?

is it possible to subscribe with a condition?

Answer (score 1):

Using queries to filter realtime messages is currently not supported. At the moment, you would need to handle that in your listener.

You might want to add a  to [this](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/issues/2490) issue to upvote the feature request.